# android google app

Tags: android

i am displaying google map but i get error i give manifest and main xml files please correct me

this is my android manifest xml:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">    
    <activity android:name=".MapsActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">                  
   <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />           
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

main.xml:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView 
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="0VwTqHDTTNQOdV9uedg-srDDhQbOnIihpl23zIA"
    />
```

logcat file error:

```
04-06 15:40:14.919: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(466): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps/net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps.MapsActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps.MapsActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps-2.apk]

04-06 15:40:14.919: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(466): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps.MapsActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/net.learn2develop.GoogleMaps-2.apk]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

outside the activity tag but inside the application tag.
For example:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"> 
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />     
    <activity android:name=".MapsActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">                  

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Check now.

Comment: how to show the map for a particular country for example india,delhi

Comment: you must have the latitude and longitude of that particular place and then pass it to GeoPoint constuctor.See http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html.